# unicorn_rails command not found in shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run `unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D` in my project directory， it's ok.

But when I use a shell script to run this command, get errors:

```
unicorn_rails: command not found
```

my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
. /etc/init.d/functions
cd /data/projects/entos/current
unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
action "start success" /bin/true
```

Comment: I suppose you are managing your dependencies with bundler and unicorn_rails is provided by a gem, try prefixing your command with `bundle exec`

Comment: mybe I get the reason,  when I delete `. /etc/init.d/functions` from the shell script, it's running ok.

Comment: When you use the . to run a script, it may mess with your environment, since the script is executed in your current shell instead of a seperate one

Comment: you are right, when I use . in the shell, I must run 'source ${my default ruby path}'.